# PhantomJS - Element is not currently interactable

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I'm currently using PhantomJS + Selenium to populate some form fields but having weird results.  50% of the time, the test runs fine.  The other 50% it errors out and gives me the following

> {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be
>   manipulated"

I'm doing the following to make sure the page is loaded.

> ```
> private static boolean waitForJQueryProcessing(WebDriver driver,
>         int timeOutInSeconds) {
>     boolean jQcondition = false;
>     try {
>         new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds) {
>         }.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
>
>             @Override
>             public Boolean apply(WebDriver driverObject) {
>                 return (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driverObject)
>                         .executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
>             }
>         });
>         jQcondition = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
>                 .executeScript("return window.jQuery != undefined && jQuery.active === 0");
>         return jQcondition;
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         logger.debug(e.getMessage());
>     }
>     return jQcondition;
> }
> ```

And then to interact with the element(s):

```
pageWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By
                    .cssSelector("#myForm-searchDate")));

            driver.findElement(
                    By.cssSelector("#myForm-searchDate"))
                    .sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
            driver.findElement(
                    By.cssSelector("#myForm-searchDate"))
                    .sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
            driver.findElement(
                    By.cssSelector("#myForm-searchDate"))
                    .sendKeys(MY_TEST_DATE);
```

I could see if it failed all the time, but it doesn't fail all the time so it's hard to repeat the results when debugging.

Edit 1.  I've tried swapping following the comment below; however, it doesn't work. I've since come to realize this seems to only happen when I fire up several (5+) instances of PhantomJS at once.

Comment: What if you would use `visibilityOfElementLocated` instead?

Comment: I'll give it a shot - the javadoc says "presenceOfElementLocated"  not necessarily mean that the element is visible so it's possible the page isn't fully  loaded when I'm trying to hit the object